# Save SVG in Memory Stream to input it into a PDF (C# OxyPlot and QuestPDF)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am currently using the OxyPlot and QuestPDF libraries to be able to generate a PDF with charts. I have designed a pie chart and a bar chart. I am currently saving the charts, exporting them to SVG, inside a folder, and then adding them to the PDF. I would like to change this and save them in memory and then yes, add them to the PDF.
According to the documentation I read from the OxyPlot library, it has an option to save the plot to a PNG in memory, but then I don't know how to insert it into the PDF:

```
var stream = new MemoryStream();
var pngExporter = new PngExporter { Width = 600, Height = 400, Background = OxyColors.White };
pngExporter.Export(plotModel, stream);
```

I leave below the code that I am using to export the graph, in SVG format, and saving it in a folder. And then, I add it to the PDF. This is how I generate the SVG and export it:

```
using (var stremPieChart = File.Create("pieChart.svg"))
    {
           var exporter = new OxyPlot.SvgExporter { Width = 400, Height = 300, UseVerticalTextAlignmentWorkaround = true };
           exporter.Export(newPieModel, stremPieChart);
    }
```

And so I add it to the PDF:

```
.Element(element =>
{
    element
         .PaddingTop(-13)
         .PaddingLeft(4)
         .AlignCenter()
         .Canvas((canvas, size) =>
         {
              var pieChartSvg = new SKSvg();
              pieChartSvg.Load("pieChart.svg");
              canvas.Scale(0.65f);                         
              canvas.DrawPicture(pieChartSvg.Picture);
         });
});
```

I hope you can help me! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I couldn't save the svg in memory because the library doesn't allow in-memory export. So, I had to modify the logic to be able to save the svg to a temporary file and then consume and delete it. This is how I got the code:

```
.Element(element =>
{
     element
         .PaddingTop(-13)
         .PaddingLeft(4)
         .AlignCenter()
         .Canvas((canvas, size) =>
         {
              string pieChartTemp = Path.GetTempFileName();
              using (var stremPieChart = File.Create(pieChartTemp))
              {
                   var exporter = new OxyPlot.SvgExporter 
                   { 
                       Width = 400, 
                       Height = 300, 
                       UseVerticalTextAlignmentWorkaround = true 
                   };
                                                            
                   exporter.Export(newPieModel, stremPieChart);
              }

              var pieChartSvg = new SKSvg();                                         
              pieChartSvg.Load(pieChartTemp);
              canvas.Scale(0.65f);                          
              canvas.DrawPicture(pieChartSvg.Picture);  
                                                  
              File.Delete(pieChartTemp);
         });
});
```

As you can see, I first created a temporary path and then generated the .svg on that path.
Then to load the SVG, I insert the temporary path.

Comment: I updated my answe. Hopefully, that can solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Since SVG is just text, you can probably save it in `MemoryStream` instead of `FileStream`, export it to array of bytes and then using `encoding.GetString()` to get the resulting text content of svg.

If this works, when loading your image you can `pieChartSvg.FromSvg(svg)` it.

like so:

```cs
string svgString;
using (var stremPieChart = new MemoryStream())
{
    var exporter = new OxyPlot.SvgExporter { 
        Width = 400, 
        Height = 300, 
        UseVerticalTextAlignmentWorkaround = true 
    };

    exporter.Export(newPieModel, stremPieChart);
    
    /// UTF8 or whatever the encoding may be, anyways...
    svgString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stremPieChart)
}
```

and later

```cs
.Element(element =>
{
    element
         .PaddingTop(-13)
         .PaddingLeft(4)
         .AlignCenter()
         .Canvas((canvas, size) =>
         {
              var pieChartSvg = new SKSvg();
              pieChartSvg.FromSvg(svgString);
              canvas.Scale(0.65f);                         
              canvas.DrawPicture(pieChartSvg.Picture);
         });
});
```

## Update

According to `OxyPlot`'s github repository, even though not documented, `SvgExporter` seem to have a method named `ExportToString` which works better with my example and doesn't create problems about the stream  type.

relevant code: [here (line 115 - 123)](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/blob/develop/Source/OxyPlot/Svg/SvgExporter.cs)

That said, my example could be like:

```cs
string svgString;
using (var stremPieChart = new MemoryStream())
{
    var exporter = new OxyPlot.SvgExporter { 
        Width = 400, 
        Height = 300, 
        UseVerticalTextAlignmentWorkaround = true 
    };
   // CHANGE HERE!
    svgString = exporter.ExportToString(newPieModel); 
}
```

and later

```cs
.Element(element =>
{
    element
         .PaddingTop(-13)
         .PaddingLeft(4)
         .AlignCenter()
         .Canvas((canvas, size) =>
         {
              var pieChartSvg = new SKSvg();
              pieChartSvg.FromSvg(svgString);
              canvas.Scale(0.65f);                         
              canvas.DrawPicture(pieChartSvg.Picture);
         });
});
```

Comment: I'll be testing it and I'll let you know.